# If the EU considers a group to be a terrorist group, does that mean every EU member also does?

Tags: european-union, terrorism

https://www.theguardian.com/world/2017/jul/26/eu-court-upholds-hamas-terror-listing

> The European Union’s top court has ruled that the Palestinian Islamist
> movement, Hamas, should remain on the EU terrorism blacklist.
>
> The EU originally listed the organisation as a terror group in 2001 in
> a move that froze its assets within the member states.

According to the article, the EU top court rules that Hamas was a terrorist group. My question is whether a country that is also a member of the EU can officially remove Hamas from their own terrorist group or whether the EU top court speaks for every European country. My thinking is that while the EU top court may have a say over whether an EU member must sanctions a group, it doesn't have a say on whether a group should be considered by all member states to be a terrorist group. I am thinking this is the case, because the EU doesn't consider the Muslim Brotherhood to be a terrorist group while Germany does.

Comment: You have shared your thoughts on the matter, but could you also share what research you have done to find an answer?

Comment: Your final conclusion about Muslim Brotherhood has its logic inverted. Europe often sets a minimum standard. Countries may add to that, but not remove.